# Join query in Access 2013

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Currently have a single table with large amount of data in access, due to the size I couldn't easily work with it in Excel any more.

I'm partially there on a query to pull data from this table.

- 7 Column table
- One column `GL_GL_NUM` contains a transaction number. ~ 75% of these numbers are pairs. I'm trying to pull the records (all columns information) for each unique transaction number in this column.

I have put together some code from googling that hypothetically should work but I think I'm missing something on the syntax or simply asking access to do what it cannot.

See below:

```
SELECT SOURCE_FUND, GLType, Contract, Status, Debit, Credit, GL_GL_NUM
FROM Suspense
JOIN (
SELECT TC_TXN_NUM TXN_NUM, COUNT(GL_GL_NUM) GL_NUM
FROM Suspense
GROUP BY TC_TXN_NUM HAVING COUNT(GL_GL_NUM) > 1 )  SUB ON GL_GL_NUM = GL_NUM
```

Hey Beth is this the suggested code? It says there is a syntax error in the FROM clause. Thanks.

SELECT * from SuspenseGL

JOIN (

SELECT TC_TXN_NUM, COUNT(GL_GL_NUM) GL_NUM

FROM Suspense

GROUP BY TC_TXN_NUM

HAVING COUNT(GL_GL_NUM) > 1

Comment: First row are my columns/fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want detailed results (all rows and columns) or aggregate results, with one row per tx number?

If you want an aggregate result, like the count of distinct transaction numbers, then you need to apply one or more aggregate functions to any other columns you include.

If you run

```
SELECT TC_TXN_NUM, COUNT(GL_GL_NUM) GL_NUM
FROM Suspense
GROUP BY TC_TXN_NUM 
HAVING COUNT(GL_GL_NUM) > 1
```

you'll get one row for each distinct txn, but if you then join those results back with your original table, you'll have the same number of rows as if you didn't join them with distinct txns at all.

Is there a column you don't want included in your results?  If not, then the only query you need to work with is

```
select * from suspense
```

Considering your column names, what you may want is:

```
SELECT SOURCE_FUND, GLType, Contract, Status, sum(Debit) as sum_debit, 
sum(Credit) as sum_credit, count(*) as txCount
    FROM Suspense
    group by
    SOURCE_FUND, GLType, Contract, Status
```

---

based on your comments, if you can't work with aggregate results, you need to work with them all:

```
Select * from suspense
```

What's not working?  It doesn't matter if 75% of the txns are duplicates, you need to send out every column in every row.

---

OK, let's say

```
Select * from suspense
```

returns 8 rows, and

```
select GL_GL_NUM from suspense group by GL_GL_NUM
```

returns 5 rows, because 3 of them have duplicate GL_GL_NUMs and 2 of them don't.

How many rows do you want in your result set?  if you want less than 8 rows back, you need to perform some sort of aggregate function on each column you want returned.

Comment: Hey Beth
Yes I need detailed transaction results- so for each unique "GL_GL_NUM" I need the information for that whole record. I need to be able to send things out for more research. I wish I could just look at sums.

Comment: Also for the first piece of code you sent, I get an error " Syntax error missing operator in query expression, on the first line.

Comment: no, if you can't use aggregate results of grouping by txn, then you're left with using the detailed results which means all columns of all rows.

Comment: Are you suggesting this as the setup??

SELECT * from SuspenseGL
JOIN (
SELECT TC_TXN_NUM, COUNT(GL_GL_NUM) GL_NUM
FROM Suspense
GROUP BY TC_TXN_NUM 
HAVING COUNT(GL_GL_NUM) > 1

Says there is a syntax error in the FROM clause, sorry I'm a complete novice at this. I'll post this in my original question too as the formatting got lost in this comment.

Comment: Hey I actually tried out the agg results and I think this will do the trick. I think I misunderstood this as a "total" of everything. Believe this is exactly what I need. Thanks so much.

Comment: I'm so relieved!  Pls upvote and/or accept if this helped.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like the following:

```
SELECT S.* FROM
SUSPENSE AS S 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT GL_GL_NUM, MIN(ID) AS ID FROM SUSPENSE
            GROUP BY GL_GL_NUM) AS S2
ON S.ID = S2.ID
AND S.GL_GL_NUM = S2.GL_GL_NUM
```

Which would return a single row for a unique gl_gl_num.  However if the other rows have different data it will not be shown.  You would have to either aggregate that data up using `SUM(Credit)`, `SUM(Debit)` and then `GROUP BY the gl_gl_num`.

I have attached a SQL Fiddle to demonstrate my results and make this clearer.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8284f/2

Comment: i think this query will return all records, except those where gl_gl_num is null

Comment: It says "circular reference in definitions caused by ID"